# How can I get wstring_convert::to_bytes to throw a range_error exception?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, unicode, std, visual-studio-2015

I am using `std::wstring_convert` to convert a wstring into a multibyte string as follows:

```
    // convert from wide char to multibyte char
    try
    {
        return std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().to_bytes(wideMessage);
    }

    // thrown by std::wstring_convert.to_bytes() for bad conversions
    catch (std::range_error& exception)
    {
        // do something...
    }
```

In order to unit test the block I have commented as `do something...` I wish to pass a wstring that will throw a `std::range_error` exception.

However, I have not been able to formulate such a wstring that will fail such a conversion.  The wstring will use UTF16 and I have been reading about high and low surrogates.  For example, a UTF16 character of D800 followed by "b" should be invalid.  `std::wstring(L"\xd800b");` fails to compile on the same grounds possibly.  If I create a wstring such as below it will not throw the exception on conversion:

```
std::wstring wideMessage(L" b");
wideMessage[0] = L'\xd800';

// doesn't throw
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>>().to_bytes(wideMessage);
```

Is there a suitable wstring I can use to throw an exception during the conversion?

I have tried 5.1, 5.2 and 5.3 from [this link](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt).  I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Which compiler and STL are you using? This works (or, throws) exactly as expected for me using clang/libc++ 3.6.

Comment: If you want to throw an exception, you could always manually throw one.  Maybe hide it in an `#if` block so it's only visible during testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft's implementation of `std::codecvt_utf8` appears to successfully convert any UTF-16 code unit into UTF-8—including surrogate pairs. This is a bug, as surrogates are not encodable. Both libc++ (LLVM) and libstdc++ (GCC) will correctly throw a `std::range_error` and fail to convert unpaired surrogates.

Looking at their code, it appears that the only way for it to throw is if a character is greater than the `Maxcode` template parameter of the facet. For example:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x1>>
```

Comment: Maybe I should be using `codecvt_utf8_utf16` as I know the source is UTF16 (and `codecvt_utf8_utf16` does throw on the examples that passed in my previous testing).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by **一二三** (accepted answer) Microsoft's implementation of `codecvt_utf8` appears to be bugged.

I know the strings I am dealing with are always UTF16, and I want to convert to UTF8.  I ended up changing the implementation as follows:

```
    // convert from wide char to multibyte char
    try
    {
        return std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16 <wchar_t>>().to_bytes(wideMessage);
    }

    // thrown by std::wstring_convert.to_bytes() for bad conversions
    catch (const std::range_error & exception)
    {
        // do something...
    }
```

The following will now throw correctly:

```
std::wstring wideMessage(L" b");
wideMessage[0] = L'\xd800';

// throw std::range_error
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>().to_bytes(wideMessage);
```

I would have never found this bug without unit testing!

Comment: Did you report this bug on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio)?

Comment: @jamesmcnellis nope, didn't read up on what the standard says.  Could be implementation specific.